# How to print/select multiple page ranges with XtraReport

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

I know there is a way to print one range of pages (from-to) with (WinForms) XtraReport, even the default print dialog shows this option already.

> Print pages: <#from>-<#to>

My question is: is there a way to do many page ranges, MSWord style?

> Print pages: <#page>;<#from>-<#to>;<#otherpage>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you export a pdf at first. You can export it to a stream. Set the export options and print the stream then.

```
XtraReport1 report = new XtraReport1();
PdfExportOptions pdfOptions = new PdfExportOptions();
pdfOptions.PageRange = "1, 3-5";

report.ExportToPdf(myStream, pdfOptions);
```

Never tried this out but maybe this is a possible solution for you.